# Is there a "Sounds-Like" string matching algorithm implemented in Dutch?

Tags: soundex

I know about the Soundex and Double-Methaphone algorithms for "sounds-like" stringmatching in English. Where can I find a similar algorithm, or a port of one of the algorithms for the Dutch Language?

Comment: Did you have any luck (six years down the road)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only after the algorithm, I would check [nltk](http://www.nltk.org) out. If you supply the data, you might be able to test some with the FSTs (Finite State Transducers) contrib by Edward Loper and Steven Bird. Or perhaps use data from the "Alpino Dutch Treebank", which is distributed along with nltk.